# Programatically add new app to Facebook Developers Panel

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I am working on a white label project, which will be replicated frequently.
Every app will have Facebook social login, but I need to create a Facebook app in Facebook Developers panel for every replication (+20 per day).
I am looking for some solution to add facebook apps programatically, so I could add this phase to my replicate procedure.
It could be webrequest wrapper, macro, or something like that.
What would you recommend for this problem?

Comment: I’d strongly recommend that you let your customers create their own app ids. Otherwise, your developer account getting blocked by Facebook for whatever reason could affect _all_ your customers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to create Apps programmatically with the API. You should consider using the same App, i assume it´s for the same topic anyway.

Other solutions without the API are most likely not allowed, and you would have a hard time getting through the captcha - it´s there for a reason.